# A Question Regarding Consistent Fragments of Naive (Ideal) Set Theory

Tags: reference-request, logic, set-theory

It is well known that Naive (to some, otherwise known as Ideal) set theory, that is, the set theory generated by the axioms:

(EXT)  (x)(x $\in$ A  iff  x $\in$ B) iff A=B

(COMP) ($\exists$y)(x)(x $\in$ y iff $\phi$(x))

is inconsistent.

However, if one restricts $\phi$ to formulas using only conjunction and disjunction (as Thoralf Skolem does in his paper "Investigations On A Comprehension Axiom Without Negation In The Defining Propositional Functions", to use this as an example) one can show (as does he) that there exist domains (i.e. models) that satisfy both EXT and COMP i.e. that for these "positive propositions" (Skolem's term) Naive (Ideal) set theory is consistent.  I will define the theory EXT + COMP for such $\phi$ that restriction to such $\phi$ which makes EXT + COMP consistent as a consistent fragment of Naive (Ideal) set theory.

My question is this:  Has a maximal consistent fragment of Naive (Ideal) set theory been discovered yet?  If so, can someone provide the citation or link to the paper(s) the result is contained in?

Comment: Perhaps see "Maximal consistent sets of naive comprehension" by Luca Incurvati and Julien Murzi https://sites.google.com/site/lucaincurvati/publications They develop a simple extension of some old results of McGee on maximal consistent sets of the T-schema.

Comment: @GME:  Thanks.  I have generated a hard copy and am in the process of reading it now.  To make sure I am understanding Incurvati's and Murzi's result, are they saying in essence that even given a maximal consistent fragment of naive (Ideal) set theory relative to the paradoxes, this maximal consistent fragment will not be able to decide whether, say, CH or $\lnot$CH in that 'maximal consistent' fragment (in other words, that maximal consistent fragment generates a 'multiverse')?

Comment: I haven't read the paper carefully enough to say, sorry! But any maximal consistent set of sentences in the language of set theory will either contain CH or ~CH (otherwise it wouldn't be maximal).

Comment: @GME:  The paper you mention speaks of incompatible maximal consistent sets satisfying COMP (should also satisfy EXT as well...), (see pg. 12 and also Example 1 on page 5).  Let COMP$\_1$ be one maximal consistent  fragment of COMP and COMP$\_2$ be another, maximal consistent fragment of COMP such that they are mutually incompatible.  Then here exists a formula $\phi$ such that if COMP$\_1$ $\vdash$ $\phi$ then COMP$\_2$ $\vdash$ $\lnot$$\phi$.

Comment: That's right. Any two maximal consistent sets will differ on some $\phi$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @GMO:  What you are missing is that COMP generates both maximal consistent sets of instances of COMP (COMP$\_1$ and COMP$_2$) which derive $\phi$ (from COMP$\_1$, say) and $\lnot$$\phi$ (from COMP$\_2).  What was hoped for, apparently, was that by restricting COMP to (as Incurvati and Murzi state in their paper) "sets with all instances of (NC [Naive comprehension, i.e. just COMP--my comment]) that are admissible according to 'Maximally Consistent'" would form a single maximally consistent set of instances of COMP (the background set theory of the 'Universe view" of set theory).

Comment: (cont.) What Incurvati and Murzi nicely show is that they end up with the set-theoretic Multiverse....

Comment: Why do you think I was missing that? That there are many different max. con. sets of naive comp. is the point of J and L's paper. As I said, it's an unsurprising simple generalisation of old results by McGee on the T-schema. And it answers your question: yes, there are max. con. instances of comp. (by a trivial application of Zorn's lemma), and as a bonus: there isn't a single such set (since any set of sentences can be coded as a set of instances of comp.). That the result impacts on the multiverse debate would take serious philosophical work over and above `oh, look! what a lot of models!'.

Comment: @GME:  I hope I didn't offend you by my previous comment--if I did, I apologize.

Comment: You didn't; don't worry!

Comment: @GME:  It is also interesting to note that these maximal consistent sets of instances of Naive comprehension are not recursively axiomatizable.  If one assumes that at least a proper subset of these are consistent with EXT(this would seemingly form the maximal consistent fragment of Naive set theory I was looking for, though not just one, of course), could one interpret, say, ZFC (+extra axioms) in this fragment?

Comment: It depends on the background theory. But in general, I wouldn't have thought so. The existence of max. con. sets of NC + Ext is provable using Zorn's lemma over $P(\omega)$. That's probably doable in second-order arithmetic plus a choice principle.

Comment: @GME: What I am suggesting (since Incurvati's and Murzi's maximal consistent sets of instances of NC are not recursively axiomatizable) and ZFC (if I understand correctly) is, allow one of sets of max.con. instances of NC to be the set-theoretic background since the existence of these max. con. sets of instances of NC can be proved without recourse to a background theory (or so it seems...).